# XML namespaces and XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an application that has to load XML document and output nodes depending on XPath.

Suppose I start with a document like this:

```
<aaa>
  ...[many nodes here]...
  <bbb>text</bbb>
  ...[many nodes here]...
  <bbb>text</bbb>
  ...[many nodes here]...
</aaa>
```

With XPath `//bbb`

So far everything is nice.

And selection `doc.SelectNodes("//bbb");` returns the list of required nodes.

Then someone uploads a document with one node like `<myfancynamespace:foo/>` and extra namespace in the root tag, and everything breaks.

Why? `//bbb` does not give a damn about `myfancynamespace`, theoretically it should even be good with `//myfancynamespace:foo`, as there is no ambiguity, but the expression returns 0 results and that's it.

Is there a workaround for this behavior?

I do have a namespace manager for the document, and I am passing it to the Xpath query. But the namespaces and the prefixes are unknown to me, so I can't add them before the query.

Do I have to pre-parse the document to fill the namespace manager before I do any selections? Why on earth such behavior, it just doesn't make sense.

**EDIT:**

I'm using:
`XmlDocument` and `XmlNamespaceManager`

**EDIT2:**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.XmlResolver = null;
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
//I wish I could:
//nsmgr.AddNamespace("magic", "http://magicnamespaceuri/
//...
doc.LoadXML(usersuppliedxml);
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes(usersuppliedxpath, nsmgr);//usersuppliedxpath -> "//bbb"

//nodes.Count should be > 0, but with namespaced document they are 0
```

**EDIT3:**
Found an article which describes the actual scenario of the issue with one workaround, but not very pretty workaround: http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/01/09/How-to-query-a-XPath-doc-that-has-a-default.aspx

Almost seems that stripping the xmlns is the way to go...

Comment: Could you add the pertinent bits of code? (Instantiating XmlDocument, XPath, etc)

Comment: Ok, edited the post, see Edit2.

Comment: @Coder: You are saying that an unexpected input results in unexpected output for a given process. **That's the use case for validation**.

Comment: "and extra namespace in the root tag" - this is almost gibberish. I suppose you mean there is an extra namespace *declaration* in the start tag of the outermost element. Is it a default namespace declaration (`xmlns="..."`)? or is it a declaration for myfancynamespace (`xmlns:myfancynamespace="..."`)? Only the former would affect the namespace of `<bbb>`. You haven't shown us what the input XML looks like, nor described it clearly, which makes it hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: When I said 'You haven't shown us what the input XML looks like' I meant the one that caused the problem.

Comment: @Coder, if you're trying to save users some trouble, please *don't* teach them that the XPath expression `//foo` should match any element regardless of its namespace. That will just cause them (and all of us) more trouble in the future. If the input document has elements in the wrong namespace, that document is invalid and should be rejected. Your tool will convince them that their document is fine, and then they will be all the more confused when they feed it to the next downstream program and it chokes.

Comment: This Q&A solved my problem. However, when searching I didn't know the namespace was a concept at fault. My problem was that my xpath searches were simply returning nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing the whole point of XML namespaces.

But if you really need to perform XPath on documents that will use an unknown namespace, and you really don't care about it, you will need to strip it out and reload the document.  XPath will not work in a namespace-agnostic way, unless you want to use the `local-name()` function at every point in your selectors.

```
private XmlDocument StripNamespace(XmlDocument doc)
{
    if (doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI.Length > 0)
    {
        doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "");
        // must serialize and reload for this to take effect
        XmlDocument newDoc = new XmlDocument();
        newDoc.LoadXml(doc.OuterXml);
        return newDoc;
    }
    else
    {
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is super useful.  I've implemented a StripNamespaces() method in some of my own projects, but this is far more elegant than mine.  I'm totally borrowing this. :)

Comment: Stripping the namespaces is the easiest approach, as otherwise I need to create a user prefix, and users can't know that. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: It's important to point out that this function does not strip out all namespaces in a document; it apparently is intended to remove any default namespace declaration from the outermost element of a document whose outermost element is in any namespace (default or otherwise). Kind of a strange spec, but if the whole document is in the default namespace, and has no default namespace declarations lower down in the doc, it will do what you want.

Comment: @LarsH, that's correct.  I was using it specifically for xhtml documents which did meet that description.

Comment: @DWRoelands, this routine is courtesy of [pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/keith/archive/2005/10/19/15714.aspx), where you can find further discussion of the technique (which I fully admit is a hack).  Should have mentioned that, but I did leave the attribution in my copy :)

Answer (score 6):

`<myfancynamespace:foo/>` is not necessarily the same as `<foo/>`.

**Namespaces do matter.** *But I can understand your frustration* as they usually tend to breaks codes as various implementation (C#, Java, ...) tend to output it differently.

I suggest you change your XPath to allow for accepting all namespaces. For example instead of

```
//bbb
```

Define it as

```
//*[local-name()='bbb']
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: It's the user that inputs the XPath, so I'm working on assumption that if he entered "//foo", then he expects "foo" from the default namespace, which is not necessarily "myfancynamespace", but if he enters "//ns1:foo", then he should select the "foo"'s of namespace "ns1", no matter what is the real URI of that namespace. Feels like a simple scenario...

Comment: If the user inputs XPath then he must understand about namespaces and its implications. This is the least understood feature of XML so I can see that you probably have a few issue with users but let them know about `local-name()` and they should be able to pick it up quickly.

Comment: @Aliostad: +1 ***"If the user inputs XPath then he must understand about namespaces"***. I agree.

Comment: Yes, but given a xmlns default namespace "a:b:c" and tag "bbb", user can't write a query "//a:b:c:bbb" because it's invalid. For that I need to add a prefix into name table, say "ns1"->"a:b:c", and only then user can ask for "//ns1:bbb".

Comment: @Coder: you're confusing namespace prefixes with namespace URIs. XPath doesn't support `//NSURI:foo` syntax where `NSURI` is a namespace URI. If you're trying to support that, use `//*[namespace-uri() = 'a:b:c']`. That **is** valid XPath.

Comment: 'so I'm working on assumption that if he entered "//foo", then he expects "foo" from the default namespace' - yes you're right, but that expression means foo in the default namespace *of the XPath environment*, whereas you seem to be thinking of the default namespace *of the XML document* (at element `foo`). It's confusing that these can be different, but if you think about validating XML documents from many different sources, you'll see why they must be distinct.

Comment: This answer is very useful for small documents with namespaces you don't need and likely 90% of users.
Even when namespaces might be needed, you can ignore them sometimes if there is a certain structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should describe a bit more detailed what you want to do. The way you ask your question it make no sense at all. The namespace is just a part of the name. Nothing more, nothing less. So your question is the same as asking for an XPath query to get all tags ending with "x". That's not the idea behind XML, but if you have strange reasons to do so: Feel free to iterate over all nodes and implement it yourself. The same applies to functionality you are requesting.

Comment: Given random XML document DOC, select all nodes "bbb" in the default namespace. Or Xpath query "//bbb" with no regards to namespace.

Comment: @Coder: The "default namespace" wouldn't be the one for selecting `<myfancynamespace:foo/>`...

Comment: @Coder, in the previous comment you posed two different (incompatible) specs. The latter makes sense, and it sounds like you know how to do that. But 'Given random XML document DOC, select all nodes "bbb" in the default namespace' means that the behavior of your app will change, depending not on what namespaces the elements are in, but depending on *which namespace is declared as the default*! That totally breaks the semantics of namespaces. Namespace declarations and prefixes are specified to be transparent. Only the name and namespace-URI of each element should determine its identity.

Comment: @Coder - in my preceding comment, I was assuming that by "the default namespace" you meant the default namespace of the XML document, at each `bbb` element. If you meant the default namespace of the XPath environment, then ignore most of my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LINQ XML classes like [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). They greatly simplify working with namespaces.