# XML not well formed - Xpath request

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm meeting a problem with an XPath request.

```
<mainNode id="id35" soapenc:root="0">
    <node1 xsi:type="soapenc:string">response1</node1>
    <node2 xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>
    <node3 xsi:type="soapenc:string">response2</node3>
    <node4 xsi:type="soapenc:string">response3</node4>
    <node5 href="#id156"/>
</mainNode>
```

My XPath Request :

**/mainNode/node1/text()**

The result :

**ERROR - Seem like XML is not well formed:The prefix "soapenc" for attribute "soapenc:root" associated with an element type "mainNode" is not bound.**

Any idea ?

PS : I get this XML File from a SOAP WebService

Comment: Is the example XML a full file? It seems that the `soapenc` namespace is not declared -- you should find `xmlns:soapenc="http://some.url/something`in it.

Comment: I think you can also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745798/wsdl-type-soapencstring-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see a full sample XML, but it sounds like your issue is related to namespace management. You also do not specify which language you are using, but have you seen [XML namespaces and XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5702610/1422377). The below is an exert from @harpo answer that shows how to strip namespaces from an XML doc if you really do not care about them.

> "if you really need to perform XPath on documents that will use an
>   unknown namespace, and you really don't care about it, you will need
>   to strip it out and reload the document. XPath will not work in a
>   namespace-agnostic way, unless you want to use the local-name()
>   function at every point in your selectors."

```
private XmlDocument StripNamespace(XmlDocument doc)
{
    if (doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI.Length > 0)
    {
        doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "");
        // must serialize and reload for this to take effect
        XmlDocument newDoc = new XmlDocument();
        newDoc.LoadXml(doc.OuterXml);
        return newDoc;
    }
    else
    {
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you copy someone else's answer instead of referring to them or closing the question as a duplicate? Also, we do not know what programming language the OP uses and this C# excerpt might be utterly useless here.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I linked to the original question and answer, gave credit to Harpo's original answer. The reason for the quoted duplicate is to make sure future readers benefit in-case the original is removed from SO. I think you will find this is good practice if you read the FAQs.  As I said in my answer the OP did not make his programming choice clear.

Comment: I do read a lot about what should be posted as a separate answer, and your post does certainly not qualify as an answer. If you are concerned about the the question you linked to being removed from Stackoverflow, why should a highly-upvoted answer be removed, but not this one here? That said, it's true that content from _elsewhere_ should be included in an SO answer for the reason you gave. How about extending your post to make it an answer in its own right?